# Is there a functionality in XSLT through which i can put a test condition on a range of values

Tags: xslt, time, xslt-1.0, date-range, ibm-datapower

For an exampple i want to test if the time (customized variable here) is between 1345:59 - 1400:00 Hrs
I am not sure if this is the right way of doing this.

Is there a way i can apply a range for the test condition. Like its true if the current time is between this range otherwise not.

Please let me know if there is any functionality in XSLT 1.0

`<xsl:when test="(($curHour = '13' and $curMin &gt;= '45' and $curMin &lt;= '59' ) or ($curHour = '14' and $curMin &gt;= '00' and $curMin &lt;= '30' ))">`

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us **exactly** what the given **time**  looks like?

Comment: GIven time is actually system current time broken into 24hrs, 60min and 60sec. What is the difference between 'or' and 'and' condition in XSLT?   <xsl:variable name="curHour">
         <xsl:value-of select="substring($curTime,12,2)"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="curMin">
         <xsl:value-of select="substring($curTime,15,2)"/>

Comment: "*GIven time is actually system current time broken into 24hrs, 60min and 60sec.*" Doesn't really answer my question. -- "*What is the difference between 'or' and 'and' condition in XSLT?*" Uhm, the same as it is in any other language? And in logic in general?

Answer (score 0):

If what you're given is already broken into hour and minute, you could do:

```
<xsl:variable name="minutes" select="60 * $curHour + $curMin" />
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="826 &lt;= $minutes and $minutes &lt; 840">
...
```

This returns true when the time given by the two variables is between 13:46 (inclusive) and 14:00 (exclusive).

---

### Edit:

If not, then you could streamline the process by calculating the $minutes variable directly from the $curTime parameter as:

```
<xsl:variable name="minutes" select="60 * substring($curTime,12,2) + substring($curTime,15,2)" />
```

(based on what you showed in the comments).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to treat the whole `HHmmss` time value as a single number, e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="timeNum" select="number(concat(substring($curTime, 12, 2),
         substring($curTime, 15, 2), substring($curTime, 18, 2))" />
```

(offsets taken from your comment, which are consistent with an ISO8601 timestamp format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ`).  This number can then be directly compared with the target times

```
<xsl:when test="$timeNum &gt; 134559 and $timeNum &lt;= 140000">
```